# How to fix etoolboox error? BibLaTex using bibstyle=uni-wtal-ger

Tags: biblatex, etoolbox

I'm trying to use BibLaTeX with `citestyle=authoryear-ibid` and `bibstyle=`[`uni-wtal-ger`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/uni-wtal-ger)

My `main.tex` looks like this:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize=auto,oneside,fontsize=12pt,toc=bib]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,%
    sorting=nyt,%
    citestyle=authoryear-ibid,%
    bibstyle=uni-wtal-ger,%
    hyperref=auto,%
    maxnames=2,%
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

But I struggle with an `etoolbox` Error:

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./main.out) (./main.out)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bookmark.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/bkm-pdftex.def))

! Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifcbx:omiteditor' undefined.
```

I think there might be a problem with the `uni-wtal-ger` Package, because the problem disappears when I use something like `bibstyle=draft`.

Using only `style=uni-wtal-ger` without defining a `citestyle` works, but does not lead to the wished result.

Comment: `uni-wtal-ger` is based on `biblatex-dw`'s `authortitle-dw` and that style expects that its bibliography and citation style are used together.

Comment: `uni-wtal-ger` was last updated in 2013 and `biblatex-dw` development also seems to be dormant at the moment. `uni-wtal-ger` is actually only a thin wrapper around `authortitle-dw`, so that could easily be replaced/reworked, but `authortitle-dw` is harder to replace by a standard style (or `biblatex-ext` style): All doable, but depending on what features you want, it may be some work.

Comment: BTW: `hyperref=auto,` is the default setting, so you can just remove it from your `biblatex` options.

Comment: One last thing before I shut up: `uni-wtal-ger` is an author-title style, so in its bibliography the year comes towards the end of the entry. If you want to cite in author-year fashion it is usually advisable to move the year closer to the beginning of the entry (after the author/editor name) so that the year is more prominent and your readers will find it easier to match citation labels to bibliography entries.

Comment: @moewe thanks for your answer, I think I will look for an other way to get the required format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uni-wtal-ger` is based on `biblatex-dw`'s `authortitle-dw` style. The styles of the `biblatex-dw` family have a very tight integration between citation and bibliography style that essentially means that a bibliography style from `biblatex-dw` has to be used together with a citation style from `biblatex-dw`.

As I mentioned in the comments `uni-wtal-ger` hasn't been updated since 2013 and development of `biblatex-dw` (last updated in December 2016) appears to be dormant as well. The styles still work as intended, but modifications can get increasingly complicated, so if you need to adjust them it may be a better choice to go for a different base altogether.

Here is an attempt to reproduce `uni-wtal-ger` with a more modern base (`biblatex-ext`) and make it an author-year citation style. (This won't be a perfect emulation of `uni-wtal-ger`, but it should be a start. If you need additional tweaks, feel free to ask new questions.)

Note that I made the style slightly more author-year-y than `uni-wtal-ger` (years come after the author/editor in the bibliography). It is possible to move the year to the back of the entry, but then the year might be harder to find for your readers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-ibid,
  innamebeforetitle=true, innameidem=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.8\baselineskip}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  and      = {u\adddot},
  editor   = {Hg\adddot},
  editors  = {Hg\adddot},
  byeditor = {hg\adddot\thinspace v\adddotspace},
  thiscite = {hier\addcolon\thinspace},
  number   = {H\adddot},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addspace\slash\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\space\midsentence}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\newcommand*{\voldatedelim}{\addspace}
\newcommand*{\datenumdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\voldatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit*{\datenumdelim}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \usebibmacro{location+date}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\space}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[s.][12]{worman}
dolor \autocite{geer,nussbaum,cicero,pines,westfahl:space,markey,baez/online}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma / Ryde, Ulf (1998): ”Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments“. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19, H. 4. S. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

---

If you insist on using `uni-wtal-ger` with a standard citation style, you can try the following, which should avoid the errors, but may produce unexpected results in some edge cases (because the underlying structure from the citation file `biblatex-dw` relies on is missing).

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  bibstyle=uni-wtal-ger, sorting=nyt,
  citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
]{biblatex}

% list of bools defined by standard-dw.cbx (copied from there)
\providebool{cbx:authauthxref}
\providebool{cbx:authedxref}
\providebool{cbx:citeauthor}
\providebool{cbx:citeauthorfoot}
\providebool{cbx:citeauthornormalfont}
\providebool{cbx:citeauthornamefirstfull}
\providebool{cbx:citeauthornamefull}
\providebool{cbx:citedas}
\providebool{cbx:edstringincitations}
\providebool{cbx:fullcite}
\providebool{cbx:idemfull}
\providebool{cbx:noidem}
\providebool{cbx:omiteditor}
\providebool{cbx:rpcited}
\providebool{cbx:xrefparent:firstcite}
\providebool{cbx:shorthandibid}
\providebool{cbx:loccit}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that is nearly what I need! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have two questions on what your wrote in the first proposal: The lines `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}` and `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` seem to have no visible effect. Could you explain what their effect is? The line `\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\space\midsentence}` produces a repeated colon in some cases. I commented the line out and got a single colon instead of a repeated.

Comment: @lumiemp Ah, yes `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}`  isn't required because it is the default already (try `\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}` to see what the command does: look at the end of the bibliography entry -- "fin" here means "final"). The effect of `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` can only be seen for entries with more than one author (have a look at the `sigfridsson` entry in the MWE for example): It makes sure all authors are listed in "family, given" order. ...

Comment: ... The repeated colon with `\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\space\midsentence}` is a bug that is going to be fixed in the next `biblatex` version (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/943, at least I hope that's it): It was an attempt to make sure "ders." is not capitalised after the colon (see the Westfahl entry).

Comment: As far as I know the bug with `\intitlepunct` usually only occurs if important fields are missing in an entry (or if the entry uses the wrong entry types), so if you see it, chances are your `.bib` entry should be different. A fix is available in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/943#issuecomment-565791295 (just replace `\newbibmacro*{in:}` with `\renewbibmacro*{in:}` to avoid a warning). If you think you have found a case where the bug occurs with a complete entry that is not missing important data, I'd love to hear about it.